# The name of the module procedure conflicts with a name in the encompassing scoping unit

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I'm learning Fortran submodule, this is my code

```
module name1
    implicit none
    interface
        module subroutine test2(x)
            integer,intent(in) :: x
        end subroutine test2
    end interface
    contains
        subroutine test1(x)
            integer :: x
            call test2(x)
        end
end module name1


module name2
    use name1
    implicit none
    integer :: z = 22
end module name2


submodule(name1) new
    use name2
    contains
        subroutine test2(x)
            integer,intent(in):: x
            integer:: y 
            y = 2
            print *, x+y+z ,'from test2'
        end  
end submodule



program name
    use name2
    implicit none
    call test1(5)
end program name
```

But while compiling with `ifort (IFORT) 2021.3.0 20210609` it shows the following error

```
test.f90(26): error #6645: The name of the module procedure conflicts with a name in the encompassing scoping unit.   [TEST2]
        subroutine test2(x)
-------------------^
compilation aborted for test.f90 (code 1)
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Is it not a valid Fortran submodule use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining the implementation of a procedure in a submodule (a [separate module procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-fortran-aix/16.1.0?topic=subprograms-separate-module-procedures-fortran-2008)), you need the keyword `module`.

The relevant bits of your code would become:

```
module name1
  implicit none
  interface
    module subroutine test2(x)
      integer,intent(in) :: x
    end subroutine
  end interface
end module

submodule(name1) test
  module subroutine test2(x) ! Note the keyword `module`
    integer,intent(in):: x
    integer:: y 
    y = 2
    print *, x+y+z ,'from test2'
  end subroutine
end submodule
```

You can also reduce the amount of duplicated code using `module procedure`, as

```
module name1
  implicit none
  interface
    module subroutine test2(x)
      integer,intent(in) :: x
    end subroutine
  end interface
end module

submodule(name1) test
  module procedure test2
    integer:: y 
    y = 2
    print *, x+y+z ,'from test2'
  end procedure
end submodule
```

Using `module procedure` means you don't have to duplicate the arguments of the procedure `(x)` or their declarations `integer,intent(in):: x`.

Comment: Ok got it. I think keeping the arguments in the implementation is okay, as it will help you to quickly get the idea of whats input and output without looking at the interface declaration

Comment: I ran the code in question with `gfortran 7.5.0`, that does not show the error.

Comment: On a cray system with `CCE-8.7.2` it throws `"TEST2" has been use associated, therefore it must not be redeclared as a module procedure subroutine.` if I write it as `module subroutine`. There I have to write it as  `module procedure`

Comment: That sounds like a bug with cray. The two syntaxes should be equivalent. (last time I checked there was also a bug with ifort the other way around, so `module procedure` couldn't be used if any of the procedure's arguments were themselves procedures).